# Access Denied while git push

Tags: git, github, gitlab

first time git asked for username and password but  accidentally 
i have entered wrong password then i have deleted .git folder
and executed git init -> git add . -> git commit -m "comment" 
and git push -u "remote url" master
but it dose not ask for username and password it show Access denied.

Below is the Error i am getting plz help me to solve this issue.
how can i change username and password.

$ git push -u "https://gitlab.com/gawandearpan/bootprocedure.git" master
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/gawandearpan/bootprocedure.git/'

Comment: Did you set a proper origin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+forget+password

Comment: Thanks phd Worked for me